# Medical dataset for creating questionares (in csv/rdf formats so that I can import them into Neo4J directly)

Tags: medical, csv

I want to create a graph database of medical information in the form of entity nodes connected by relations and was wondering if any csv datasets existed that would allow me to directly import the data into Neo4J.

Comment: the question isn't clear. The title says "questionnaires" and the text says "trivia".

Comment: I meant it as, the graph contains them as trivia, essentially entity relation triples and I can then query them to generate questions.

Comment: On second thoughts maybe the term trivia was the wrong one.